# Home widget keyboard focus

Tags: android, android-appwidget

i'm working on an Android (4.1, 4.2) Home Widget. I create my widget and now it's on the Home Screen. When I use Android Tablet with an external keyboard, all the shortcut icons are focusable (light blue square around the icon) but my widget isn't selectable through the keyboard navigation keys.

I set the Layout of my widget focusable, clickable  and focusableInTouchMode but nothing change.

is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks